# Setting sinatra environment variables to a symbol

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm trying to set Sinatra environment variables so they pass a symbol, not just a string. Right now I get the following error message: `DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol (:development) instead.`

My `.env` file: (using dotenv gem)

`RACK_ENV=development`

My `environments.rb` file (I require this in my app.rb file)

```
environment = ENV['RACK_ENV']
db_options = YAML.load(File.read('./config/database.yml')[environment])
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_options)
```

I've try setting the .env to:

`RACK_ENV=:development`

but that throws me an error `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: try `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)` maybe?

Comment: But I want to read the hash/variables from `database.yml`

Comment: I think the default location it reads from is from `config/database.yml` (I'm not sure though...)

Comment: With Sinatra-AR, yes you're right it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sinatra-Active Record by default reads the database.yml file, it means I don't need to explicitly read that file. Instead I just wrote the following:

.env

`RACK_ENV=development`

environments.rb

```
environment = ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(environment)
```